# Can Texas really split itself into five states?

Tags: united-states

[The new episode of revisionist history](http://revisionisthistory.com/episodes/21-divide-and-conquer) claims that Texas can split parts of itself into four other states, at most, leaving five Texan states altogether.

The basis for this reasoning can be found in the opening of the [Let's Mess With Texas](http://revisionisthistory.com/pdfs/Kesavan_Paulsen.pdf) Essay by Vasan Kesavan and Michael Stokes Paulsen:

> [image: hey]

Which they say is from:

> [image]

Could Texas really split off four other states from itself right now?

Comment: This looks more like a legal question of whether there is an existing law or constitutional provision for splitting Texas, than a political question of who supports/opposes it and why.

Comment: Perhaps I’m asking this in the wrong place to begin with, but this does have a huge political bearing on it. “Texas” could effectively change their number of senators from 2 to 10 by annexing our four new states.

Comment: This is a good topic but IMHO a question that is not within site scope, in that your own source answers it (the podcast referenced basically what is the main existing scolarship on the topic. So what are you asking, "*is this legal paper wrong*"? If so, this site isn't qualified to address that). If you're asking "If they tried, would they succeed", it's not answerable because the answer likely is "depends on how eventual challenge to SCOTUS proceeds and we can't predict till SCOTUS rules")

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Law.SE or is speculative, the way it is written

Comment: @user3306356: There is the legal question, which is better on Law.SE, and there are political issues. If you want to ask about the politics then you will need to say what political question you are asking. Right now your question is a legal one.

Comment: Any state can split into substates with congressional approval (per article IV of the Constitution).  The question here is whether Texas can split _without_ congressional approval.

Comment: We have thousands of questions about laws (like [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/are-there-any-rules-laws-that-would-prevent-100-surveillance-of-capitol-wh-for?rq=1)). Questions about impeachment/parlamentary procedure/constitutions/international law/pardons/whatever. As long as they affect directly the political process they are allowed. And of course, that this question could be on-topic in law.se does not automatically make it off-topic here. Voting to reopen.

Comment: This would be better on History than Law, but I think it is on topic here.  I don't think that we should try to get deep into the details of how laws work, as we'll do it badly.  But the answer to this is simple:  No, they already formed five states from the Texas annexation, which included more than just the modern state of Texas.  And the question of whether or not Texas can split itself into five states is inherently political.

Comment: This question has been adressed on History.SE: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33668/why-does-texas-have-the-right-to-split

Answer (score 11):

#### No

The [Texas Annexation](https://www.learner.org/interactives/historymap/states_texas.html) is already spread across Texas and four other states:  New Mexico, Oklahoma (the panhandle), Kansas, and Colorado.  Texas is the only one that looks to be wholly formed from the annexation territory, but the other four include parts of such land.  As such, there is no remaining right to split Texas.  They've already been split as much as specified in the [Joint Resolution for Annexing Texas to the United States](https://www.tsl.texas.gov/ref/abouttx/annexation/march1845.html).

[image: Map of the Texas Annexation shown over modern borders]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wpdms_republic_of_texas.svg).  The full size version of that map actually shows the Texas Annexation stretching into a sixth state, Wyoming.

#### But there's a way

If Congress and the Texas legislature agree, Texas could split.  This is just to say that there is no remaining split from the original resolution.  That split has already occurred.  Any additional split would be new and in addition to the split specified previously.

Answer (score 5):

1. That law will depend on if any further law has stopped or prevented that.  That would only be appropriate for the law stackexchange.
2. Any law that exists can be undone.  We've witnessed this in the US multiple times in the last few decades.  There's even an amendment (21) that repeals an earlier amendment (18).  Outside the US, empires have stopped existing or broken apart (Soviet Union) so this could happen again anywhere and in states too.
3. If you ever visit Texas, you'll observe they tend to fly their own flag a lot.  In fact, they fly it more than many countries I've been too and they fly their flag more than the most of the rest of America flies the American flag.  Like it or not, they have a unified identity as *Texans*.  It's hard to imagine a world where a unified group of people like this would break into four states being a part of one state.  Impossible?  No.  Unlikely.  Probably for now.